# Right clicking suddenly unbearably slow in VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

I have been using VS2010 without any issues, always on the same application.  Suddenly within the last my solution has become unbearably slow when right clicking.  When doing other projects, it is fine.  The only thing I can think of that I changed was disabling the SQL Server debugging.

It happens if I right click anywhere within the code editor.  Everything freezes for about a minute and a half, then the right click menu shows up.   If I try again right away, the same thing happens.

Intellisense seems to work fine. It is only the right click.

The project is fairly big, but it has been working fine.  I am working on a 2 month old top of the line MacBook Pro (running Windows 7 64 bit in Boot Camp).  I did do the patch Tuesday big batch of Microsoft patches in the last 24 hours...

Can anyone suggest where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delay *that* long is almost always associated with network time-outs.  Use the trouble-shooting strategy demonstrated by Mark Russinovich in [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/05/26/3244913.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I tried the config file change suggested at this link with no effect.
 I restored a full backup from several days ago, and it is running fine.  Comparing the files, there are very, very few differences (besides quite a bit of code - but nothing that should be able to lock up the system when right clicking). 
I may have to restore the backup and try to merge the code changes - but I would prefer to identify the cause of this.

Comment: OK - I take it back - I think your suggestion was right.  

I was thinking about what network time outs, and the freeze reminded me of SQL server browsing and not finding a server.  My dev version of SQL is stopped when booted, so I tried starting the service.  Sure enough, right click is back to normal...  Crazy thing is, no where in the project is this SQL Server instance being used.  I have done a winmerge on the solution with a backup - and can find ZERO references to the local dev SQL server instance.  

Seems crazy - but thanks! Now to find out how to avoid having to start SQL service

Comment: Good, you found it.  View + Server Explorer.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant you nailed it. I used Process Monitor to detect that Visual Studio 2012 was attempting to connect to an external TFS server every time I right clicked. Since I had to be on VPN to access that TFS server, it was timing out. I went to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plugin-in Selection and set it back to none and now I have my speedy right click back. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 7, x64, 12GB memory, very slow right clicks:**

The following steps fixed the problem for me.  Right click is now instantaneous.  Your Mileage may vary:

I deleted the following directory:
%AppData%Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

and reinstalled these three packages from the Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate DVD

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework with this command:
\WCU\DAC\DACFramework_enu.msi

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project:
\WCU\DAC\DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service:
\WCU\DAC\TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi