# Right Pop up menu coming slowly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, setting

When i right click in the text editor in Visual studio 2008 IDE, the Pop Up menu comes at a slower pace. Is there any setting in visual studio that can control this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make VS GUI faster by disabling animation.
Uncheck "Animate environment tools" checkbox in tools - options - environment - general.
This may help...

Comment: Thanks Raiv, I tried that, but no change in the behavior. The time required for Right click pop up menu to appear is slower. It appears faded initially and then appears fully. This causes a lot of aggravation while coding. Any suggestion ???

Comment: well... then some more suggestions... 1) Try to turn off IntelliSence. If popup menu is still slow-
2) If you are using some VS plugins, like VisualAssist -try to disable them one by one and look for differences. 3) what is your hardware? for example, on ATOM-based machines VS always extremaly slow...

Answer (score 5):

After a windows crash my IntelliSense context menu (when clicked over a member/class/declaration) became very slow (~10s to open it). Solution was to close my VS2012, and delete solution cache files (solutionname.suo).

Keep in mind that .suo files are hidden.

After reloading the solution all came back to normal!

Comment: It worked for me. But please note that in VS 2017 you have a `.vs` subfolder that contains a solution folder, containing the suo file and other stuff. All the folder could be deleted, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly a timeout trying to connect to a Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.  To disable this in VS 2012:

Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection > Current Source control plugin-in > None

This worked for me and I read about it in a comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467989/1007353 .

Comment: not really a solution if you require the use of source control though is it?

Comment: @rolls right, but maybe if you need the source control plugin you can still try this answer to rule out whether that is causing your slowdown